Are there any languages with under 50% lexical similarity that could reasonably be considered mutually intelligible?
When I was reading about mutual intelligibility one thing stood out to me: lexical similarity doesn't seem to directly correlate with mutual intelligibility potential. This makes sense because there are other factors like grammar, sounds, writing systems, etc. involved.
For example I read that Russian and Ukrainian are about as similar as Spanish and Italian. Spanish and Italian are rated at 82% lexical similarity and are partially mutually intelligible. However Russian and Ukrainian only have 62% lexical similarity.
So based on that it appears possible for languages to be at under 50% lexical similarity yet exhibit (low but relatively manageable) mutual intelligibility.
A candidate for such a position is Polish and Russian at 38% shared words. Some people were able to apparently (with a lot of difficulty) put together Polish and Russian conversations, including Ecolinguist from Poland.
Are Polish and Russian mutually intelligible? If not are they close enough that this pair's near mutual intelligibility implies it is possible to have mutual intelligibility at under 50% given 38% is significantly lower than 50%?
Are there any pairs around the world with this criteria (including Slavic languages)?

I'd want to know what the source is for these figures. Calculations by M. N. Saenko show more than 70% lexical similarity between any pair of Slavic languages in basic vocabulary, so the numbers mentioned in those websites must be looking at total vocabulary.

I agree. They are probably total vocabulary.

There's also the matter of what constitutes a shared word. Thirty and coach are exactly cognate with Danish tredive and kusk ‘driver’, but they’re pretty impossible to recognise in the other language, and the meaning isn’t even particularly close in the second pair. Are those ‘shared words’? And if so, what use are shared words when they don’t provide any significant help?

Prior to the breakup of Yugoslavia, weren't "Serbian" and "Croatian" considered a single language ("Serbo-croatian") where the only difference was that Serbs wrote it with a Cyrillic alphabet and Croats with a Latin alphabet?

@JeffZeitlin linguistically, they still are.

Up to about maybe 1450, before any hint of the great vowel shift, loss of final -e, the predominance of do-support, and decline of function words remaining important elsewhere in the Germanic family such as worth the verb, English speakers would likely have found it easier to communicate with speakers of Frisian, Low Saxon, and some Dutch dialects, despite the considerable amount of entrenched French vocabulary. The Wikipedia page for Middle Frisian outright makes the claim, “As late as 1599, the London dramatist Thomas Dekker could introduce whole scenes in the mixed Frisian-Dutch argot of the coast in The Shoemaker's Holiday, in confidence that his English-speaking audience could follow it.”, though this seems a bit spurious to me. But you’re right that lexical similarity is not the end-all be-all–go see about Anglish, a project aiming to realize the English of the world where the Normans didn't invade, and sure, some Germans and Dutchmen who already know English might find it neat, but it's not in any meaningful way ‘closer’ to them–we’ve been separated by the sea itself for over a thousand years; we are not going to keep up with each other like Iberians can, “farseer” for television or no. Another possibility: though the mutual intelligibility between Maltese and Tunisian Arabic is by our time 50%, it plausibly also at some point in the late medieval to early modern period occupied this odd zone, since in strict genetic terms it is closer to Tunisian than Tunisian to Libyan.
